# How to remove useless space in Rust string without using regex

Tags: rust

Is there a way in Rust to in a string:

1. reduce double spaces to one and
2. remove spaces before and after `\n`, `\r\n`, tabs?

As you can imagine this is all text coming from form inputs like `text` and `textarea`.

All this:

1. without using regex
2. with unicode chars

**Some tests to satisfy are:**

```rust
#[test]
fn test() {
    assert_eq!(magic("  ".to_string()), " ");
    
    assert_eq!(
        magic("     a l    l   lower      ".to_string()),
        "a l l lower"
    );
    
    assert_eq!(
        magic("     i need\nnew  lines \n\nmany   times     ".to_string()),
        "i need\nnew lines\n\nmany times"
    );
    
    assert_eq!(magic("  à   la  ".to_string()), "à la");
}
```

In golang I'm using:

```golang
func Magic(s string) string {
    return strings.ReplaceAll(strings.Join(strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
        if r == '\n' {
            return false
        }

        return unicode.IsSpace(r)
    }), " "), " \n", "\n")
}
```

Comment: What about CRLF `\r\n`? Do you want those normalized to `\n` or left alone?

Comment: The same for CRLF of course. Sorry.

Comment: What about tabs and other forms of non-newline whitespace?

Comment: Yeah. I know tab are a problem. If possible tabs too. The reason is to remove as much as possible useless spaces...

Comment: What about spaces _after_ newlines?

Comment: Those too. You mean, is input from forms: text and textarea inputs mostly.

Comment: Is it difficult?

Comment: The only difficulty is handling your first test case. How important is it that a string of all whitespace is collapsed to a single space, rather than an empty string?

Comment: Maybe is not that important. Maybe an empty string is ok.

Comment: What's the appeal of avoiding regex? They were made for exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I worked out:

```rust
fn magic(input: &str) -> String {
    input
        // trim leading and trailing space
        .trim()
        // split into lines
        .lines()
        .map(|part| {
            // for each line
            part
                // trim leading and trailing whitespace
                .trim()
                // split on whitespace,
                // including the space where the string was split
                // into the resulting parts
                .split_inclusive(char::is_whitespace)
                // filter out substrings containing only whitespace
                .filter(|part| !part.trim().is_empty())
                // collect into a String for this line
                .collect()
        })
        // collect into a Vec of Strings
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        // join those Strings with a newline
        // back into the final String
        .join("\n")
}
```

It doesn't handle a string containing only whitespace the same, instead it will return an empty string. Also, it will normalize all line breaks to `\n`.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad1bebb19f28417ecac33b799c5f61bf)

There is a slightly different version that's probably faster, with fewer allocations:

```rust
fn magic(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut output: String = input
        // trim leading and trailing space
        .trim()
        // split into lines
        .lines()
        .flat_map(|part| {
            // for each line
            part
                // trim leading and trailing space
                .trim()
                // split on whitespace
                // including the space where the string was split
                .split_inclusive(char::is_whitespace)
                // filter out substrings containing only whitespace
                .filter(|part| !part.trim().is_empty())
                // add a newline after each line
                .chain(["\n"])
        })
        // collect into a String
        .collect();
    
    // remove the last newline
    output.truncate(output.trim_end().len());
    
    output
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d95ecc1ca3c8a4f5c76ae426a803122)

I'll let you decide which you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second one panics with: `attempt to subtract with overflow` using `assert_eq!(magic("   "), "");`.

Comment: I benchmarked and apart this overflow issue the second one is x2 faster.

Comment: Made a small edit that should resolve the panic.

Comment: Thank you! I found this one slighty faster (using criterion for benchs): https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-remove-useless-space-in-rust-string-without-using-regex/82285/4. The second one (not the one with `intersperse`).